# JavaFX column/cell-value not updating

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I recently started programming an application with JavaFX (jdk 1.8.0_66). I got a few table(view)s, one of them should be an overview about all the 'subscription'-objects. Therefore I create the tableview and populate it with an observable list:

```java
TableView subsTable = new TableView(SubscriptionAdmin.getObservableSubList());
```

My table for example kinda looks like this:

```
Subscription | Participants  
Netflix      | 4  
Whatever     | 8
```

```java
TableColumn<Subscription,String> nameCol = new TableColumn("Subscription");
nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("name"));
TableColumn<Subscription, Integer> partCol = new TableColumn("Participants");
partCol.setCellValueFactory(
                cellData -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(cellData.getValue().getParticipants().size())
);
```

Now whenever I add an participant to my list, the number in the according cell should be increased by one but it won't - except I restart the application. Hope someone of you can help me / explain me what's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the table (or rather - the cell) has no way of knowing the data changed. 
If `getParticipants` returns an `ObservableList` the best solution would be to create a binding to its' size -

```
partCol.setCellValueFactory(
            cellData -> Bindings.size(cellData.getValue().getParticipants())
);
```

If it is not an `ObservableList` you may consider changing it to be one (after all - you wish to update the display when it changes). Otherwise you will have to manually update the table whenever you change the size of the list.

Edit: You may need to either add `.asObject()` to the binding call, or else change the type of the column to `Number` and not `Integer`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620552/why-does-longproperty-implement-propertynumber-but-not-propertylong) for discussion.

Comment: Hey, that's cool! Thank you for that fast reply! I was about to report about the converting fail, when you already augmented your answer! Thanks.