# ChangeListener as a private class

Tags: java, generics, javafx, observable, changelistener

I'm developing a game and I'm currently trying to implement a ChangeListener for the character's Health.
I've defined a getter for the healthProperty which is actually an instance of SimpleIntegerProperty

I've already got it working as a lambda expression:

```java
character1.healthProperty().addListener( ((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        System.out.println(observable);
        System.out.println(oldValue);
        System.out.println(newValue);
    }) );
```

When the character takes damage it prints out:

IntegerProperty [value: 333]

350

333

The thing is that I want to be able to reuse this listener for every character in-game, so I'd like it to be an inner class, but I can't get the types right, so far i've got this:

```java
private class HealthPropertyListener implements ChangeListener<IntegerProperty> {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<IntegerProperty> observable, Integer oldValue, Integer newValue) {
        // Do something
    }
```

It doesn't compile cause it tells me that i'm not overriding the method correctly.

If I do it this other way, it works, but I'll have to cast the Object to Integer in order to use them. Is there a way to escape that ugly cast?

```java
private class HealthPropertyListener implements ChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        //Do something
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `SimpleIntegerProperty` implements `ObservableValue<Number>`. Therefore you need a `ChangeListener<Number>`. The correct signature for the `changed` method in for this type parameter would be

```
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue)
```

See [javadoc for `ChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html#changed-javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue-T-T-) and [javadoc for `SimpleIntegerProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleIntegerProperty.html)

Answer (score 2):

`SimpleIntegerProperty` implements `ObservableValue<Number>`, so the correct signature should be:

```
public void changed (ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldValue, Number newValue)
```

As an aside, with Java 8 you don't really have to create a class for this - you can use a method:

```
private void healthChanged (ObservableValue<? extends Number> obs, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
    ...
}

...
// inside a method in the same class
character1.healthProperty().addListener(this::healthChanged);
```

See also: [Why does LongProperty implement Property but not Property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620552/why-does-longproperty-implement-propertynumber-but-not-propertylong)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [changed](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html#changed%28javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue,%20T,%20T%29) method of `public interface ChangeListener<T>`:

```
void changed(ObservableValue<? extends T> observable, T oldValue, T newValue)
```

Based on this the correct form is:

```
private class HealthPropertyListener implements ChangeListener<IntegerProperty> {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends IntegerProperty> observable, IntegerProperty oldValue,
            IntegerProperty newValue) {
    }
}
```

The answer on this question can be helpful:

[When do Java generics require <? extends T> instead of <T> and is there any downside of switching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897935/when-do-java-generics-require-extends-t-instead-of-t-and-is-there-any-down)