# How to convert ObjectProperty<String> to StringProperty in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

There is a method to convert `ObjectProperty<Integer>` into `IntegerProperty`. Here it is:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/IntegerProperty.html#integerProperty-javafx.beans.property.Property-

Why there is no analogous method to convert `ObjectProperty<String>` to `StringProperty`? How to convert then?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Both `StringProperty` and `ObjectProperty<String>` implement `Property<String>`, which is usually specific enough.   The problem with `IntegerProperty` etc. is that they implement `Property<Number>` rather than `Property<Integer>`, `Property<Long>` etc. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620552/why-does-longproperty-implement-propertynumber-but-not-propertylong and https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8125218

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at the source for `integerProperty`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/javafx/beans/property/IntegerProperty.java#IntegerProperty.integerProperty%28javafx.beans.property.Property%29), all it does is a bidirectional binding (and unbinding in finalize).

You could copy what `integerProperty` does, and modify it to use `StringProperty`:

```
public static StringProperty makeStringProperty(final Property<String> property) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(property, "Property cannot be null");

    return new StringPropertyBase() {
        {
            bindBidirectional(property);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getBean() {
            return null; // Virtual property, no bean
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return property.getName();
        }

        @Override
        protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
            try {
                unbindBidirectional(property);
            } finally {
                super.finalize();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I've modified it a bit here so it does not use internal packages.